# Java BigInteger alternative

Tags: java, biginteger

Is there a way to improve [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) performance with caching?

When you operate on `BigInteger` it always creates a new `BigInteger`. For example, when you multiply two big integers, a new `BigInteger` is created to host the result. I want to use some mutable version of a `BigInteger` that will update one of the fields with the result.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. If you want to increase the performance, don't use `BigInteger` in the first place. What exactly is the performance bottleneck you want to fix?

Comment: A technical answer would be to write your own implementation, but what @Tunaki said is probably better. If you're using `BigInteger` in such an intensive way that it's actually affecting performance, you should probably use something else. If you have to use `BigInteger`, then you accept the performance hit that comes with it.

Comment: In other words, you are looking for some sort of `ModifyableBigInteger`?

Comment: following up on the other comments, you can actually open the source code for BigInteger and create your own class that handles these operations the way you'd like them to be handled

Comment: @tobias_k yep some thing like that

Comment: @Tunaki I am implementing integer factorization, I am using gcm(), multiplication, mode, division, kind of all what BigInteger got to offer. It's not that trivial to decide not to work with BigInteger...

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman: Like others said, there won't be a lot of difference in performance whether you can do: `a.multiply(b);` or `a = a.multiply(b);`. Fact is that an intermediate value must be created anyway, and that this is only assigned to the original at the very last moment, even in a MutableBigInteger. I have implemented my own version of a (Mutable)BigInteger in Delphi (no Java,sorry), and that is what I found out. Modifying the data while they are being used is not a good idea, so you create a new BigInteger, calculate everything into that BigInteger and then at the end assign it back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are mutable "versions" of `BigInteger` out there (e.g: https://github.com/bwakell/Huldra ) Or you can roll your own. Using a mutable object may reduce the pressure on the GC. You really should benchmark your application to see if this is worth the effort.

Comment: Actually, Java also has a MutableBigInteger class, but it is used internally only.

Comment: Interesting - used by BigInteger too

Answer (score 14):

I doubt that the performance of your algorithm will improve if you could somehow do this, but the main principle is that `BigInteger` is immutable.  You cannot perform an operation on it without generating a new instance, and there are good reasons to want this behavior - namely, if you have multiple threads operating on a single `BigInteger`, you can rest assured that these threads aren't overwriting that `BigInteger` directly*.

If you don't desire this behavior, your only option is to create a new class, but bear in mind that you will still be dealing with the immutability of `BigInteger`s at *some* layer.

<sup>*:  Y'know, so long as you're not *reassigning* the variable...</sup>

Comment: "you will still be dealing with the immutability of BigIntegers at some layer." - or, you could re-implement big integers from scratch (yuck).

Comment: @JanDvorak:  Why reinvent the wheel? :P

Comment: @Makoto: wheels are re-invented all the time. In this case, one would very likely do it to get the mutable BigInt class one needs. ;-) Fact is that it can be done without dealing with the immutable nature of BigInteger.

Comment: Having mutable alternative would greatly improve memory re-allocations. To your argument about the mutitheading - what's wrong about having dedicated mutable and immutable versions for different purposes? Same as we have normal and concurrent collections

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for is unlikely to be in any way more performant except when all you want to do is add. The reason for this is that the number of bits in the result of almost any mathematical operation (other than the aforementioned `add`) is a different size than the original number. You will **almost always** have to allocate a new number of the results and the copy it back over the original so all you are actually doing is making it slower.

If, however, all you need to do is add/sub then this is doable and could actually be a little faster as there will be no allocation of the new array for addition.

Almost all other functions would be better delegated to the BigInteger class.

```
class MutableBigInteger {
    BigInteger n;

    public MutableBigInteger add (MutableBigInteger n) {
        this.n = this.n.add(n.n);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only true assuming you are performing just one operation, but consider the next example: a*b/c*d and it turns to be more complicated. Also this allows me to reuse my BigInteger for future operations.

Comment: If there s a carry on the addition of the highest linbs, the array must be 1 limb largercthan the originals. Also, two different values often don' t have the same size, so a reallocation must often take place anyway, even on addition or subtraction.

Comment: The benchmarks at [Huldra](https://github.com/bwakell/Huldra) seem to disagree with you. I wonder how those benchmarks would do against Java 8 BigInteger